# appending data to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have used the following code to initialize a dictionary from the list of keys

```
z=df1[2].value_counts().keys().tolist()
mydict=dict.fromkeys(z,None)
```

further, I have used

```
value=df2[2].value_counts().keys().tolist()
counts=df2[2].value_counts().tolist()
    for j,items in value:
        if mydict.has_key(items):
            mydict.setdefault(items,[]).append(counts[j])
```

it is generating the following error

> mydict.setdefault(items,[]).append(counts[j])
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Append works for arrays, but not dictionaries.

To add to a dictionary use `dict_name['item'] = 3`

Another good solution (especially if you want to insert multiple items at once) would be: `dict_name.update({'item': 3})`

The NoneType error comes up when an instance of a class or an object you are working with has a value of `None`. This can mean a value was never assigned.

Also, I believe you are missing a bracket here:    `mydict.setdefault(items,]).append(counts[j])`
It should be: `mydict.setdefault(items,[]).append(counts[j])`

Comment: i corrected it by changing mydict=dict.fromkeys(z,None) to mydict=dict.fromkeys(z,[])

Answer (score 6):

```
mydict = {}
print(mydict) # {}
```

Appending one key:

```
mydict['key1'] = 1
print(mydict) # {'key1': 1}
```

Appending multiple keys:

```
mydict.update({'key2': 2, 'key3': 3})
print(mydict) # {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
dict["key"] = value_list
```

so in your case:

```
mydict["key"] = z
```

as described here:
[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that you are trying to append to the result of `mydict.setdefault()` which is actually None as that method returns nothing. Apart from that do also take note of other answers that to a dictionary in python, you do not `append`