# Keeping the values separately in the dictionary with for loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I've reviewed many questions in StackOverflow that may be related to my question
[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops/3294899), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325708/appending-data-to-python-dictionary/51325861), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary/59053661), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112471/creating-a-dictionary-while-iterating-through-multiple-for-loops/33112563) None of them are related to my question. Apart from these, I examined almost 20 questions here.

I created a sample code block to explain my problem simply. My aim is to add data to a dictionary in for loop.

When I run the code block below, the output is as follows.

```
dictionary = defaultdict(int)

for uid in range(10):
    for i in range(5):
        distance = 2*i
        dictionary[uid] = distance
```

**Output**
[image]

My aim is to keep the key value in each loop and add on it.

**Expected Output:**

```
{0: {0,2,4,6,8,}, 1:{0,2,4,6,8,}, 2:{0,2,4,6,8} , ...
```

**My Solution**

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(int)
    
    for uid in range(10):
        for i in range(5):
            distance = 2*i
            dictionary[uid].append(distance)
```

My solution approach is also not working there is a problem

Comment: You just need to declare your defaultdict type as `list` instead of `int`

Comment: do you need it to be a `list` or a `set`? the expected output shows `set`

Comment: `dictionary = defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(set)
for uid in range(10):
    for i in range(5):
        distance = 2*i
        dictionary[uid].add(distance)
```

**Output (`dictionary`):**

```
> defaultdict(set,
            {0: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             1: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             2: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             3: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             4: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             5: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             6: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             7: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             8: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
             9: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}})
```